# Installing ubuntu on an old HP [Missing BootManager]

Tags: window-manager

I have an old hp computer that is "missing bootmanager" and the only way to fix it is to use the recovery disc, which I no longer have. I don't care about the windows on it anymore, I only want Ubuntu.

I've successfully created the usb stick to install ubuntu, now i'm just unsure how to actually use it on the old hp.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

General installation process:

1. Plug in the USB-stick.
2. Boot the computer.
3. Check BIOS settings. Make sure to set the computer to boot from USB flash stick. I usually press the [del] key. It may be different for other computers.
4. If the computer boots up to the installation medium, then you are on your way.

Since you mentioned this is an old computer, did you check if the computer meets the minimum system requirements? I'm asking because ubuntu comes with a lot of flavors/versions. The official unity-based ubuntu is a bit resource-heavy. You may want to check out lubuntu or xubuntu, although I'm not too familiar with these.

Many linux installers also act as live CDs. You can try running the system without actually installing it first. This allows you to check if your hardware is supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

### You can follow these steps for successfully installing ubuntu.

1. Create the Ubuntu liveCD or Pendrive and follow these steps.
2. Turn on the computer and immediately press the F10 key repeatedly until a BIOS Setup screen opens.
3. If nothing happens, press the F1 key repeatedly.
4. In the BIOS Setup utility,search for boot menu:

   > For BIOS version 6 or less go to Boot Tab.
   >   For BIOS version 7 or more  go to Storage Tab.
5. Search for boot menu option and change the boot device to pendrive or CD.
6. Reboot your computer and boot install ubuntu.

Note:While installing select "Erase disk and install ubuntu" for installation type. This will erase Windows and other drives and install ubuntu on your PC.